# What is a natural way to say 'People will resent them all the more'?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot

I participated in a group discussion with French people and I got stuck for words when I wanted to say 'People will resent them all the more' like below.

---

- 'If they think they can improve the situation by controling the region overly strictly, they've got it all wrong. People will resent them all the more.'

Answer (score 7):

You might have translated it to:

> *S'ils croient pouvoir améliorer la situation par une prise de contrôle autoritaire de la région, ils ont tout faux. **Le peuple leur en sera d'autant plus hostile.***

or

> ***...Les habitants n'en seront que plus hostiles.***

or

> ***...la population n'en sera que plus hostile.***

Comment: Le peuple, les habitants, oui. Mais ici, j'aurais plutôt dit : *les gens* car avec la seule connaissance de la phrase, je ne sais pas bien qui sont les *people* en question.

Comment: @aCOSwt *Les people* serait un contresens ;-) J'aime assez *peuple* car il rend bien l'impression d'une opposition peuple contre pouvoir que dégage la question, et préfère *habitants* à *gens* parce que je trouve que *les gens* est d'un registre moins soutenu que le reste de la phrase. J'ajoute une troisième proposition pour répondre à ton commentaire avec un terme plus neutre.

Comment: Why does the first option have both leur and en?

Comment: @Aerovistae *leur* refers to  *they* and *en* refers to *controlling the region overly strictly*.

Answer (score 3):

There is more than one way to express the idea, but I'd say something like:

> S’ils croient améliorer la situation en contrôlant la region d’une main de fer, ils se trompent lourdement. **Les gens ne leur en voudront que plus**.

Answer (score 0):

Ces traductions conviennent toutes les deux également, à mon avis;

> S'ils pensent rendre de la stabilité à la région au moyen d'une répression sévère, il font fausse route. **Ils ne récolteront de la population qu'une plus grande aversion**.
>
> Si  leur intention est de restaurer l'ordre dans la région en restreignant les libertés, ils sont totalement dans l'erreur. **Ils n'en tireront qu'un ressentiment accru de la population.**

Comment: La seconde proposition me semble naturelle, mais pas la première.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez En quoi n'est-elle pas  naturelle ? La tournure passive  avec « des »? Oui, ce n'est pas usuel. Je pourrais peut être changer cela ; cela me semble mieux avec  « de la population » ou « par la population », plus naturel, comme vous dites. D'accord avec ça ?

Comment: Oui c'est sûrement ça qui me gênait. Mais le sens est un peu trop fort aussi. Il y a quand même une grosse différence entre du ressentiment et de la haine.

Comment: "tireront" avec un t à la fin. Le sujet est "ils" (3e personne du pluriel).

Comment: @BernardMassé Merci pour la grammaire, mais ce n'est pas le problème (dans ce cas particulier tout au moins…) ; l'étourderie est ce qui est en cause…